# Получить все результаты из одного документа

Tags: c#, search, elasticsearch

Народ делаю автокомплит, ищу по массиву тэгов в документе , как находится первый подходящий item из массива в результат выводится он , остальные пропускаются , например

**# Документ:**

```
 "tags": [
  "art",
  "artwork",
  "random"
]
```

**# Поиск:**

```
"suggest": {
    "mysearch": {
      "prefix": "ar",
      "completion": { "field": "tags"}
```

**# Результат:** (как видим выводится 1 результат 'art', а 'artwork' потерян)

```
{
  "text": "art",
  "_score": 1.0,
}
```

Как сделать чтобы в результате выводились все совпадение из одного документа?

**# Что ожидаю:**

Результат(или такой):

```
{
  "text": "art,artwork",
}
```

Результат(или такой):

```
{
  "text": "['art','artwork']",
}
```

Результат(или такой):

```
[{
  "text": "art",
   "_id": "documentID_1",
},
{
  "text": "artwork",
  "_id": "documentID_1",
}]
```

Comment: programming language?

Comment: C# [elasticsearch nest] on backend. But answer can be on elasticsearch standart query language REST APIs

Comment: Я написал по-английски просто так, случайно. Вообще у нас русско-язычное сообщество. Я добавил метку в вопрос.

Comment: Интересно как это `как находится первый подходящий item из массива в результат выводится он , остальные пропускаются` согласуется с этим `как видим выводится 1 результат 'art', а 'artwork' потерян`? Покажите свой код для ясности происходящего.

Comment: а что не понятного? Вроде выше и документ есть и запрос есть и результат этого запроса

Answer (score 0):

берите результат из _source, не из text

Comment: Пожалуйста, дайте более развёрнутый ответ.  Поясните, откуда взять `_source` для результата?

Comment: Когда Вы делаете запрос suggest, Elastic помимо поля текст возвращает поле _source, которое содержит исходный документ, который будет содержать объект tags в полном виде. Пример https://ibb.co/YB6m5f1

Comment: Вы можете дополнить ответ кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1119426/edit).

Comment: Ожидал такой ответ. Он неверный. Вы предлагаете организовать вручную на клиенте поиск еще раз... например из примера из вашего _source  вернется  
"tags": [
  "art",
  "artwork",
  "random"
]
Мне  "random" не нужен , я его не искал!